# The dollar ($) prefixed field '$avg' in 'average.$avg' is not valid for storage

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I am trying to use $avg function inside set clause of mongo update function, but getting below error.
[image]
I am using the commands given in mongo documentation (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/  example 2).

As suggested by sushant mehta, I have tried in shell version 4.2 in which the above commands are working fine. Basically I want to use logical expressions in set clause of update command, something like below:
[image]

I know the logical expressions inside switch statement will all result false, I am just trying to explore. Is there a way to achive this in shell version 3.0.8?

Comment: Do check mongo version, this is available in latest 4.2 version only.

Comment: Thanks for your response,  I have updated my question based on your comments. Please guide me if there is a way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

The `$avg` is an aggregation pipeline operator and you **cannot use that with update for Mongodb version lower than 4.2**. Do check at what stages it is available [**$avg**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/)

To solve this problem in case you are on lower versions of mongo, first you can find averages of tests via `$project`

```
var results = db.collection.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        testsAvg: {
            $avg: "$tests"
        }
    }
}]);
```

Which outputs:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e996a5871068e0c9da406"),
  "testsAvg" : 92.33333333333333
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e996a5871068e0c9da407"),
  "testsAvg" : 90.66666666666667
}
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5d5e996a5871068e0c9da408"),
  "testsAvg" : 75.66666666666667
}
```

Then based on those ids you can update the documents by iterating through results and update average for each record.

```
while (results.hasNext()) {
    var doc = results.next();
    db.collection.update({_id: doc._id},
                  { "$set": { "testAvg": doc.testsAvg }});
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ambian for your response. I have tried this approach and Its working. Can you please see my updated question and guide me?

Comment: I have tried the same approach using $project. Below are my two commands,  Its working :)   var results = db.students3.aggregate([{ $project: { grade: {$cond: { if: { $gte: [ 300, 250 ] }, then: 30, else: 20 }} } }]);
while (results.hasNext()) {
    var doc = results.next();
    db.students3.update({_id: doc._id},
                  { "$set": { "grade": doc.grade }});
}

Comment: @Gopi Lower mongo versions doesn't support combining fields,conditionals (mostly part of aggregation pipeline operators) etc. in the update statement.

Answer (score 0):

To  the  Mongodb  Documents  ,  I also  meet the same problem .

**if you try to use  update  with  inner  field  or  to   calculates a new field  ,you have to put  it in  an array  .**

for  your error .
do it like  this .

```
db.students3.update(    { },  [ { $set: { average : { $avg: ["$a","$b"] } } }]  ,{ multi: true } )
```

it  works  well for me .

for your question
**Starting in MongoDB 4.2, an aggregation pipeline that modifies the matching document(s).**
it is not  suit  for  version  3.0 .
but you can find and  iterator  the  data  and caculate the value then update .